# I get a error when trying to install any package with the npm command

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

I am trying to install a package for my project with the following command

```
npm install jwt-decode
```

then I got the following error

```
npm ERR! Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0 while parsing near '<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLI...'
```

I checked if this only happens when I try to install this specific package but it happens when I try to install any other package as well.

How can this be fixed?

My versions of Angular CLI and Node are

```
Angular CLI: 7.1.4
Node: 10.14.1
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 7.2.14
```

I tried to clear the cache this didn't seem to work and I also tried to run the following commands as suggested in other posts.

```
npm config rm proxy
npm config rm https-proxy
```

but this didn't work either.

Comment: Check your package.json, whether it is in proper JSON format or not.

Comment: check your `package.json` file, wrong json

Comment: @Niraj Chauhan -- i added my package.json file

Comment: @kzrfaisal -- i added my package.json file

Comment: You're probably behind a proxy that isn't allowing you to access the registry. Removing the proxy settings isn't going to help; you need to get the correct settings, or the address of the internal registry you're supposed to be using instead.

Comment: @jonrsharpe -- thank you your answer/comment solved my problem it was our firewall that was blocking npm commands